# NHibernate concurrency

Tags: nhibernate, concurrency

I am new to NHibernate. I am curious to know if two processes on different machines pull up the same record at the same time. Both of them modify the record and one of them submits the record before the other. Will the second process roll back the transaction and throw an error message that the record has already been updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not by default. However, using `<version>` mapping will help you with this.

[version-mapping](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/#mapping-declaration-version)

[Optimistic concurrency control](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/#transactions-optimistic)